# Django admin - add custom link to change list view

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Firstly thanks for taking the time to read my problem 
I tried to add a custom button to my admin changeList view, but it always gives me  **Page not found (404)**

This my modelAdmin code:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    class Media:

        js = ('admin/js/additional_js.js',)

    model = MyModel

    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super(MyModelAdmin, self).get_urls()
        analyze_url = patterns('',
                           (r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/analyze/$', 
                        self.admin_site.admin_view(self.analyze_view))
                           )
        return analyze_url + urls

    def analyze_view(self, request, pk):
        # some code here
        HttpResponseRedirect(
            reverse('admin:myapp_MyModel_change', args=(pk,))
        )
```

My jQuery code for adding custom link to change list view:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function($) {
        $(".object-tools").append('<li><a href="analyze/" class="link">Analyze</a></li>');
    });
})(django.jQuery);
```

when I click my custom link it gives me this:

**MyModel object with primary key '3/change/analyze' does not exist.**

I see that the link does not point to the view 
Can someone help me fix this issue. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Django 1.9, the admin change url has changed to `/admin/<app>/<model>/<pk>/change/` ([release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.9/#django-contrib-admin)).

Therefore, it doesn't make sense to link to `href="analyze/"` in your html. The relative url is treated as `/admin/<app>/<model>/3/change/analyze`, not `/admin/<app>/<model>/3/analyze` as you expect.

You can probably fix the problem by changing the link to:

```
<a href="../analyze/" ...
```

Ideally, it would be better to reverse the url rather than having a relative link. I think this would make the code less fragile.

Since you are using Django 1.9, you can update your code to use a list rather than `patterns`:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

analyze_url = [
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/analyze/$', self.admin_site.admin_view(self.analyze_view)),
]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you saved my life.

Comment: by against the change you suggested gives error  **TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "list") to tuple**

Comment: I had missed out the `url()`. Not sure whether that was the problem though.

Comment: Please why the request of my analyz_view is empty, why it did not recover data from the page?

Comment: I'm not sure, but that sounds like a separate issue. Please ask a new question.

Comment: Ok, I will try to fix it, Thanks